# ArcMap 10.3 Mosaic to New Raster produce a single color output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, image-mosaic, mosaic-dataset

Here's what my final result looks like

[image: Image with unique value 1122]

The workflow is quite simple but I cannot get it go right

Create first the mosaic dataset

```
arcpy.CreateMosaicDataset_management(in_workspace="<path>/xxx.gdb", in_mosaicdataset_name="B01", coordinate_system="PROJCS['WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_31N',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['false_easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',0.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',3.0],PARAMETER['scale_factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['latitude_of_origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-5120900 -9998100 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0,001;0,001;0,001;IsHighPrecision", num_bands="", pixel_type="", product_definition="NONE", product_band_definitions="")
```

I then add my two adjacent (sslightly overlapping) rasters

```
arcpy.AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management(in_mosaic_dataset="<path>/xxx.gdb/B01", raster_type="Raster Dataset", input_path="B01_01;B01_04;",update_cellsize_ranges="UPDATE_CELL_SIZES", update_boundary="UPDATE_BOUNDARY", update_overviews="NO_OVERVIEWS", maximum_pyramid_levels="", maximum_cell_size="0", minimum_dimension="1500", spatial_reference="", filter="#", sub_folder="SUBFOLDERS", duplicate_items_action="ALLOW_DUPLICATES", build_pyramids="NO_PYRAMIDS", calculate_statistics="NO_STATISTICS", build_thumbnails="NO_THUMBNAILS", operation_description="#", force_spatial_reference="NO_FORCE_SPATIAL_REFERENCE")
```

Statistics:

```
arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(in_raster_dataset="<path>/xxx.gdb/B01")
```

Color Balancing (if I do not do this, I got an end result where there's no unique value, but the color difference in both image is too bad)

```
arcpy.ColorBalanceMosaicDataset_management(in_mosaic_dataset="<path>/xxx.gdb/B01", balancing_method="DODGING", color_surface_type="FIRST_ORDER", target_raster="", exclude_raster="", stretch_type="NONE", gamma="1", block_field="")

arcpy.BuildOverviews_management(in_mosaic_dataset="<path>/xxx.gdb/B01", where_clause="", define_missing_tiles="DEFINE_MISSING_TILES", generate_overviews="GENERATE_OVERVIEWS", generate_missing_images="GENERATE_MISSING_IMAGES", regenerate_stale_images="REGENERATE_STALE_IMAGES")
```

The part where I create the unique output end document

```
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(input_rasters="<path>/xxx.gdb/B01", output_location="<path>/xxx.gdb", raster_dataset_name_with_extension="xxx_B01", coordinate_system_for_the_raster="", pixel_type="16_BIT_UNSIGNED", cellsize="", number_of_bands="1", mosaic_method="LAST", mosaic_colormap_mode="FIRST")
```

Creating Statistics is of no help

```
arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(in_raster_dataset="<path>/xxx.gdb/xxx_B01")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Daniel. Could you please describe the input data in more detail? What type of raster data (e.g. satellite imagery etc). I'm wondering if the bit depth is off for the mosaic?

Comment: Input data are Sentinel-2 data imported into a gdb. Bit depth of both images is 16 unsigned. Overlap between images is 15km

Comment: Try Append tool in ArcMap. I tried and it worked for me.